# Add column from other data frame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = 

ID  Num
a     0
b     0
c     1
d     1
```

And 2-nd:

```
df = 

ID
a
a
b
b
c
c
d
```

I want to add `Num` column to `df` with the following rule:

If in `df1` `a` is `0`, then every `a` in `df` should be `0` and so on.

---

Desired output:

```
df1 = 

ID  Num
a     0
a     0
b     0
b     0
c     1
c     1
d     1
```

---

I did it with `if` condition, but it appears very long and hard coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
nummap = df1.set_index('ID').to_dict()['Num']  
df['Num'] = df['ID'].map(nummap)
```

output

```
In [387]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[387]: 
  ID  Num
0  a    0
1  a    0
2  b    0
3  b    0
4  c    1
5  c    1
6  d    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `merge`

```
df=df.merge(df1)
  ID  Num
0  a    0
1  a    0
2  b    0
3  b    0
4  c    1
5  c    1
6  d    1
```